# Handling NPEs for JSON

Tags: android, json

I use Jackson for unmarshalling/deserializing (JSON-to-POJO) of API responses in my Android app and the code is sprinkled with: `getJSONObject().getXXX() != null` before I use the property and I suppose there is a better way to handle null checks so, I'm looking for suggestions.

Also, for unmarshalling/deserializing, would adding a constructor, with all the properties as arguments for the constructor, the right approach for performance optimization so that jackson library parses the constructor to map the JSON property to the POJO property? I currently don't create a constructor and instead just add `getXXX()` and I started to notice that the API response for my web service is growing in size (breaking that one monolith service into multiple is in the works) so, I want to pre-emptively start leveraging best practices.

Comment: Make some utility classes for API responses to avoid repetitive code and hard mantainance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up leveraging `JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` at the class-level and I'd just check if the object (POJO) is null which works for all the properties defined in that object.